# Простакувата назва "Learn you %topic% for great good" українською

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як можна було б дотепно перекласти цю фразу [Learn you Haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)?

Ймовірно англійською малось на увазі *Teach yourself ...* як-от "Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years". Гадаю, це щось подібне до того коли люди, що не знають гаразд англійської кажуть "I will learn you" в значенні "I will teach you".

Comment: **"Чужому навчайтесь, та свого не цурайтесь!"** - далеко від дослівного, але якось одразу виникла асоціація.
Та ось як це розуміють викладачі НТУУ “КПІ”: [link](http://kpi.ua/910-5)

Comment: @link занадто далеко як на мене

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (вивчи, лісп, (або, бо-бо, !))
2. Да вивчи ж ти нарешті хаскель заради Бога!

Answer (score 2):

На *сусідньому* ресурсі, де можна вдосконалювати навички з англійської мови є [питання](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165/what-does-great-good-mean-in-tutorial-title-learn-you-a-haskell-for-great-goo) про цю книгу. Ця відповідь визнана найкращою:

> Haskell is a very mathematical programming language. It is typically
>   learned by mathematically inclined people who have big brains. That
>   makes the subject matter frightening to many people. It triggers their
>   "math anxiety".
>
> The title is deliberately silly so as not to make people feel anxious.
>   Haskell books are typically pedantic and formal. The informal,
>   grammatically incorrect, silly style of the title is kind of promise
>   to the reader that the book won't be overly pedantic and formal.
>
> I think also that the author, who is Slovenian, may be making fun of
>   his own English skills. (The English inside the book however is very
>   good.)
>
> In better English, the title might be something like, "Learn Haskell
>   for great benefit".

Щоб обіграти в назві національну особливість та неформальність обкладинки, можна вжити щось типу цього: "Покращення .Haskell вже сьогодні".

Хоча особисто мені здається, що автор просто писав про збільшення користі від знань та застосування мови.

Comment: я більше схиляюсь до ["Да вивчи ж ти нарешті хаскель заради Бога!"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17864). хоча всі відтінки гри слів буде складно передати

Comment: @Chizh, до речі так, теж непоганий варіант, хоча й доволі довга назва (ну, й теоретично може погано "зайти" тим же агностикам чи атеїстам, хоча сама вона давно стала нейтральною в плані експресії)

Comment: З огляду на вищесказане думаю що автор дослівно переклав свою думку із словенської на англійську. Можна продовжити і перекласти англійську дослівною українською: "Навчи свій Haskell для великої користі".

Comment: @Artemix, makes sense, хоча пишуть, що англійську автор знає, але це також може бути спеціальною нормою.

Answer (score 0):

*Вчи %щось% для спільного блага*.

*Great good*, *greater good* означає, що сам виконавець з цього може не отримати ніякої користі, тому все, що з цього вийде - лише збільшення добра в світі; для суспільства та людства в цілому було б корисно. Саме в такому іронічному сенсі і треба сприймати назву книжки про Хаскель і треба спробувати передати такий настрій. Просто дотепні назви не підійдуть.